# Splitting Forum into Sections?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, html, bbpress

I am trying to figure out how to create different Forum Sections to my site…a perfect example of this is:

https://pebx.pl/

By default, it seems BBPress only allows you to create (1) forum index…but, how can I create another section to split up the forum into categories – such as in those examples above?

Or see the image below .

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".slidingDiv").hide();
   $(".show_hide").show();

   $('.show_hide').toggle(function(){
       $("#plus").text("-");
       $(".slidingDiv").slideDown();

   },function(){
       $("#plus").text("+");
       $(".slidingDiv").slideUp();
   });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide" id="plus">+</a>

<div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
    Check out the updated jQuery plugin for doing this: <a href="http://papermashup.com/jquery-show-hide-plugin/" class="show_hide" target="_blank" style="display: inline;">jQuery Show / Hide Plugin</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.show_hide {
    display:none;
}
.a{
    font: 2em Arial;
    text-decoration: none
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k2k4C/)**